# Windows 10: 'gpresult' not recognized

Tags: windows-10, group-policy

windows novice here, running windows 10 on a dell i7 inspiron. In command prompt, I am able to run neither `gpresult` nor `gpresult /v` which both seem to be common uses. I can't find any installation instructions (or proof of the necessity of installation). Any such command issued returns what I presume is boilerplate, `'gpresult' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Is there a way to install it; am I issuing the prompt incorrectly or missing some prior step; or does the absence of built-in `gpresult` indicate something interesting?

Comment: Hmm. is there a `gpresult.exe` in `C:\Windows\System32`?

Comment: yes, its 216 kb

Comment: And what is the output of `where gpresult`?

Comment: where not recognized

Comment: Try `C:\Windows\System32\where.exe gpresult`.

Comment: Try running `C:\Windows\System32\gpresult.exe`. if that works then your PATH is broken.

Comment: yep that worked. how can I fix the path? thank you very much btw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### I am able to run neither `gpresult` nor `gpresult /v`

> 'gpresult' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Your path is broken.

Look for spaces in your path which shouldn't be there.

See [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them) for instructions on how to edit your path.

The default path on Windows 10 is:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
```